# For loop in R indexing on a element of a vector

Tags: r, for-loop

I have these objects in R:

```
N <- c(3,4,9)
R <- c(0.12,0.66,0.34)
P <- c(0.0024,0.0076,0.0028)
```

I am trying to make a for loop indexing according the first element of vector `N` in this way:

```
for (j in N[1]:(N[1]+3)) {
r <- R[1]
p <- P[1]
print(c(N[j],r,p))
}
```

According to me, it should return:

```
3 0.12 0.0024
4 0.12 0.0024
5 0.12 0.0024
6 0.12 0.0024
```

but it returns:

```
9.0000 0.12 0.0024
    NA 0.12 0.0024
    NA 0.12 0.0024
    NA 0.12 0.0024
```

How can I make it right?

Comment: The `for` portion resolves to `for (j in 3:6)`. On the first pass, `N[3]` is defined as `9`; second pass, `N[4]` is not defined, so it returns `NA`. Perhaps you mean to print out `j` instead of `N[j]`?

Comment: If you want different decimal representations, `print(c(..))` is not what you need. Perhaps `print(sprintf("%.0f %.2f %.4f", j, r, p))`?

Comment: It is exactly what I was looking for. Print j solves it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A little more explanations for new programmers:

The N vector is `c(3,4,9)`, so `N[1]` = 3, `N[2]` = 4, `N[3]` = 9.
When you write `N[1]`, the computer understands the 1st element of `N`, so 3. And when you write `N[1]+3`, it understander `3+3` = 6. So the `for` loop is scanning for values of `N` in positions `N[1]` to `N[1]+3` = positions `3` to `6` = `N[3]:N[6]` = `c(9, NA, NA, NA)`, hence your output.

In your `for` loop, you want it to scan the values: `c(3,4,9)` also coded as `seq_along(N)`as in @akrun 's answer.

Answer (score 0):

A `for` loop in `R` is a for each loop, therefore, it is just the value that got looped and not the index (for subsetting).  If we want to use indexing, loop over the sequence (`seq_along`) of the vector

```
n1 <- N[1] + 0:3
 for (j in seq_along(n1)) {
  r <- R[1]
  p <- P[1]
  cat(paste(n1[j],r,p), '\n')
  }
```

-output

```
3 0.12 0.0024 
4 0.12 0.0024 
5 0.12 0.0024 
6 0.12 0.0024
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- since `j` increments from 3 to 6, you likely should be printing `j` instead of `N[j]`, since the latter is undefined after the first pass.
- you have variable number of decimals, I suggest `sprintf`.

```r
for (j in N[1]:(N[1]+3)) {
  r <- R[1]
  p <- P[1]
  cat(sprintf("%.0f %.2f %.4f\n", j, r, p))
}
# 3 0.12 0.0024
# 4 0.12 0.0024
# 5 0.12 0.0024
# 6 0.12 0.0024
```